# Can't get data back from an Ajax get request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Been playing with this for too long now!

I'm using codeigniter.

I am trying to get some data back from an Ajax get request. Simply I want to check a MySQL DB to check if there is some data in there mathcing a given date. A simple true or false will be fine for the return.

Here is my request, followed by the PHP. The PHP does return the correct result into $data, but when it gets back to the Ajax request, the alert(data) is called and shows up as blank... nothing there.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
function get_appointment_data(request_date){

    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/doctor_today/booking/retrieve_cal_data',
    type: 'GET',
    data: request_date,
    success: function(data){
                alert(data);
    }
    });
}




function retrieve_cal_data() {

    $this->load->model('Booking_model');

    $date = $this->input->get('date');      
    $data = $this->Booking_model->get_calendar_data($date);

    return $data==null;
}
```

Comment: What about first take a look what is really sended from server to browser - try some debug console

Comment: Actually, I should add, that ultimately I want to return an array of strings from the MySQL DB... that's my next step.

Comment: I don't see any echo, print or whatever. Does codeigniter output the controller's returned value? Maybe you want to try `return $data==null ? "false" : "true";` or even `echo $data==null ? "false" : "true";`.

Comment: As Basti said, echo something inside your controller and test it.

Comment: even if I replace the return with return 1; I still see alert(data) showing nothing... this is the first time I've used an ajax get request, but I am assuming they receive the returned data via a return from the url function pointed to...?

Comment: Ohh, I am echoing inside the controller. it all looks fine. However, the moment I return from the controller to the .js file where the ajax get is, I see alert(data) has nothing.

Comment: Still, did you looked at hat really is in response from server ?

Comment: Serge, from what you are saying I assume you mean look in something like the chrome inspector? I'm not familiar with using this, but from looking at the get request under 'network' I don't actually see a response. Which may explain why I see nothing. however, I know my PHP is receiving data from the MYSql DB.

Comment: To use Chrome's inspector after the page load right click inside the page and select inspect element and then select/click console and before that replace alert(data); with console.log(data), it'll better describe your problem.

Comment: You got one answer and it's true that you have to output your data inside your controller if you are not using any view to echo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with codeigniter but you must output the result of the function. Instade of 'return' you must use 'echo' to return result to ajax request.

Comment: Umm. If I use echo (in my controller) instead of return it simply outputs to the screen (the correct data!). I guess the question is, how do I get that data back to the .js file where the ajax request is? It's possible I am using ajax get in totally the wrong way, but I thought it was used to return data from the server to my javascript?

Comment: Guys, thanks. I worked it out with your help. echo ($data) was the format required! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the result, otherwise your ajax won't receive a result and the success handler won't execute. Here is what I'm going to use for this case, I'm using the simpler .post function for that task with one key difference - I specify 'json' at end of it which means I'll get a json object as a result from my .post (you can search Google for this). The next key is to use encode the result I wanna get in json format using PHP's json_encode function and echo its result. We don't really need to return a result via the normal 'return' statement. So...

The script:

```
        var url = 'http://example.com/ajax_function';
        var data = null;

        $.post(url, data, function(data) {

            if(data.ok)
                alert('Everything is fine!');
            else
                alert('Ops!');

        }, 'json');
```

The server side:

```
   function retrieve_cal_data() {

     $this->load->model('Booking_model');

     $date = $this->input->get('date');      
     $data = $this->Booking_model->get_calendar_data($date);

     echo json_encode(array('OK' => $data==null));
  }
```

If you call directly the PHP function it should output something like

```
  { "OK": "true" }
```

which later on will be translated to an javascript array

```
  data[OK] = true;
```

which you can use as you wish.

Cheers,
Stan.

P.S. I haven't tested the code but it should pretty work.